# Running Load Tests in VSTS

Tags: jmeter, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've been trying to get Jmeter load tests to run in VSTS thus far without avail. I've been back and forth (very slowly!) with the Microsoft support team about this, but as the issues are ironed out I would like to at least run a small set of load tests on our build machine using Jmeter and then have the results uploaded somehow to VSTS so they are easier to track. I have part 1 of this working: From the VSTS release definition I run a batch file that runs the load tests locally, and then generates an aggregate spreadsheet with results.

The question is - how can I get those results loaded into VSTS?

Answer (score 1):

In our case we had to export the results to xml using the jmeter.test.xmlouput configuration. Then we had a script to transform the xml in a proper Xunit result file and we finally used a publish test results to gather this file and add the results to the release. (this approach would work with build definitions too).
It's a little bit complicated, requires some scripting and surely would be easier if a dedicated task was available.

[image]

Comment: Thank-you, but I am still a little unclear. Currently I have a script that creates an aggregate xml file. How would I turn that into an Xunit results file? What does VSTS do with the Xunit results file?

Comment: When you do automated testing in VSTS either you're using mstest and VSTS can import that automatically or you have to use a collect tests results step after running your tests.  
This step "understands" Junit, Xunit, MsTest and Nunit test results files.  
However Jmeter doesn't output to these format, this is why we have to transform the file. I'll try to edit my answer to add a screenshot.