# How to run a Jmeter build definition for API test and publish results to VSTS

Tags: junit, jmeter, azure-devops

I have a [Jmeter test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DWxP.png) that I use to test some APIs with http request.

On VSTS, my team has set up Test Cases so I need to Run [automated tests from test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=vsts) to validate restJson values as shown in [part 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqZi6.png) of the previous documentation link

I already made a simple [build definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqB93.png) that successfully builds my Jmeter test plan. The problem is that I don't know what to add to my build definition to publish the results from jmeter on VSTS so I can visualize which service executed correctly as shown in the "view results tree" section shown in [Jmeter test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DWxP.png)

Note: I know I can execute jmeter test plan .jmx from the Load Test tab on vsts but I'm not testing performance, I just need to verify that each API responds with a specific status code and response data as shown in [Jmeter test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DWxP.png). The problem is that I can not associate an automated test to run a test case if I'm using the Load test.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861744/8914908) suggest to export the results from jmeter  to xml and then create a script to transform the xml in a proper Xunit result file then used to publish test results but this seems a little complicated.

I was also thinking that maybe there is a way to export my jmeter file to a junit test in java/maven that I can use to build and publish my results later on vsts but I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can also to convert the JMeter result to Junit result, and then publish the JUnit test to VSTS.

And there are multiple ways to convert JMeter result to Junit result. Below are some options:

- Option 1：Use the tool [JMeter JTL to JUnit reports converter](https://github.com/tguzik/m2u).
- Option 2: Use your own XSLT to convert JMeter to JUnit.

  You can refer the post [Convert JMeter reports to JUnit reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477077/convert-jmeter-reports-to-junit-reports) for the XSLT example.